# How to change icon in Android running app view

Tags: android, android-icons

I've added a custom launcher (adaptive and legacy) icon by building it in Image Asset Studio, but cannot figure out how to change the "running apps" view icon. New projects have the green icon, while the app I created a custom launcher now has a blue icon (which is not the custom icon I built) in the running apps view. How is this icon changed?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an emulator problem. I tested on a physical device and the blue icon was replaced with my custom icon. For those in the future that have built an icon with Image Asset Studio and are running into this problem, either test again on a physical device or create a new AVD.